# How to regist hive udf before spark read table from jdbc

Tags: sql, apache-spark, jdbc, hive, user-defined-functions

I created one UDF in hive, for example:

```
create function mydb.level as 'com.my.udf.level' using jar 
'hdfs://hadoop01:8020/user/hive/udf_jars/dbtools-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar';
```

Now , I want to read data from hive table using spark like this:

```
spark.read().jdbc(myurl, "(select level(id) from my_tbl)t", prop);
```

it was failed. 
How can I use `level()` in `jdbc` api.

Answer (score 0):

When you register Hive UDF as permanent function it's tied to database in which it was created and you need to indicate the database as well when you call the UDF. So in your case you need to call the udf as follows:

```
spark.read().jdbc(myurl, "(select mydb.level(id) from my_tbl)t", prop);
```